# How to pass data which is coming as response from backend to the another component in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, event-bus, vue-events

I am developing one page which is responsible for placing order `Cart.vue` which contains two api calls, `handleMail()` method is sending email and generating a orderID  and i am getting response from backend in network section like this.

```
   { 
     "message":"order created successfully",
     "orderID":87450588
   }
```

i am catching that orderID and stored as a orderNumber,Now i want to pass that orderNumber to another component called `orderPlace.vue` and i want to display that orderNumber inside template section.for this i am creating Event bus  it's not working ,please help me to pass orderNumber to another component ...

`Cart.vue`

```
<template>
<div class="main">

    <div class="first-section">
        <div class="content">
            <h5>My Cart({{books.length}})</h5>
        </div>
        <div v-for="book in books" :key="book.id" class="container">

            <div class="mid-section">
                <img class="img-section" v-bind:src="book.file" alt="not found">
                <p class="title-section">{{book.name}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="author-section">
                <p class="author-name">by {{book.author}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="price-section">
                <h6>Rs.{{book.price}}</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="icons">
                <i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i>
                <input class="rectangle" value=1>
                <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-grps">
            <button class="btn" v-on:click="flip()" v-if="hide==true" type="submit">Place Order</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="second -section">
        <div class="details-box">
            <input type="text" v-if="hide==true" class="initial-btn" placeholder="Customer Details" />
        </div>
        <div v-if="hide==false" class="fill-details">
            <form @submit.prevent="" class="address">
                <h4 class="heading">Customer Details</h4>
                <div class="name">
                    <input type="name" required pattern="[A-Za-z]{3,10}" v-model="name">
                    <label class="label">Name</label>
                </div>

                <div class="name">
                    <input type="text" required v-model="phoneNumber">
                    <label class="label">Phone Number</label>
                </div>
                <div class="pin">
                    <input type="text" required v-model="pincode">
                    <label class="label">PinCode</label>
                </div>
                <div class="pin">
                    <input type="text" required v-model="locality">
                    <label class="label">Locality</label>
                </div>
                <div class="address-block">
                    <input class="address" type="text" required v-model="address">
                    <label id="Add" class="label">Address</label>
                </div>
                <div class="city-landMark">
                    <input type="text" required v-model="city">
                    <label class="label">City/Town</label>
                </div>
                <div class="city-landMark">
                    <input type="text" required v-model="landmark">
                    <label class="label">LandMark</label>
                </div>
                <div class="Radio-Buttons">
                    <p>Type</p>
                    <div class="radio-btns flex-container">
                        <div>
                            <input type="radio" id="Home" value="Home" name="type" v-model="type">
                            <div class="first-radio"> <label class="home" for="Home">Home</label></div>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <input class="work-round" type="radio" id="Work" value="Work" name="type" v-model="type">
                            <div class="second-radio"> <label for="Work" class="work-label">Work</label></div>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <input class="other-round" type="radio" id="Other" value="Other" name="type" v-model="type">
                            <div class="third-radio"><label class="other-label" for="Other">Other</label></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="btn-continue">
                        <button type="submit" @click="handlesubmit();handleMail();" class="continue">continue</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import service from '../service/User';
import { EventBus } from "./event-bus.js";
export default {
   created() {
        if (localStorage.getItem("reloaded")) {
            localStorage.removeItem("reloaded");
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem("reloaded", "1");
            location.reload();
        }
        service.userDisplayCart().then(response => {
            this.books = response.data;
        })
    },
    data() {
        return {
            flag: true,
            hide: true,
            booksCount: 0,
            name: '',
            phoneNumber: '',
            pincode: '',
            locality: '',
            city: '',
            address: '',
            landmark: '',
            type: '',
            books: [],
            cart:'MyCart',
            nameField:'Name',
            phoneField:'Phone Number',
            pincodeField:'PinCode',
            AddressField:'Address',
            localityField:'Locality',
            cityField:'CityTown',
            landmarkField:'LandMark',
            orderNumber:''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        flip() {
            this.hide = !this.hide;
        },
        Togglebtn() {
            this.flag = !this.flag;
        },
        handlesubmit() {
            let userData = {
                name: this.name,
                phoneNumber: this.phoneNumber,
                pincode: this.pincode,
                locality: this.locality,
                city: this.city,
                address: this.address,
                landmark: this.landmark,
                type: this.type,
            }
            service.customerRegister(userData).then(response => {
                return response;
            }).catch(error=>{
                alert("invalid customer address");
                return error;
            })
        },
        // handleMail(){
        //     service.confirmMail().then(response=>{
        //         alert("order placed successfully");
        //          let orderNumber= response.data.orderID;
        //          this.$router.push({path: '/ordersuccess'});
        //          console.log(response);
        //          return orderNumber;
        //     }).catch(error=>{
        //         alert("Error in sending email");
        //         return error;
        //     })
        // }
        handleMail(){
            service.confirmMail().then(response=>{
                alert("order placed successfully");
                 let orderNumber= response.data.orderID;
                 console.log("my num",orderNumber);
                 EventBus.$emit("emitting-order", orderNumber);
                 this.$router.push({path: '/ordersuccess'});
                 console(response);
                return orderNumber;
            })
        },
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import "@/styles/Cart.scss";
</style>
```

`OrderPlace.vue`

```
<template>
<div class="order-place">
    <div class="image-container">
        <img src="../assets/success.png" alt="not found" />

    </div>
    <div class="title-container">
        <p>Order placed Successfully</p>
    </div>
    <div class="message-section">
        <p>Hurray!!!your order is confirmed {{orderNumber}} and placed successfully contact us in below details
            for further communication..</p>
    </div>
    <div class="title-section">
        <div class="email-us">
            <p>Email-us</p>
        </div>
        <div class="contact-us">
            <p>Contact-us</p>
        </div>
        <div class="address">
            <p>Address</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="email-sec">
        <p>admin@bookstore.com</p>
    </div>
    <div class="contact-sec">
        <p>+918163475881</p>
    </div>
    <div class="address-sec">
        42, 14th Main, 15th Cross, Sector 4 ,opp to BDA complex, near Kumarakom restaurant, HSR Layout, Bangalore 560034
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        <router-link to="/dashboard" class="btn">Continue Shopping</router-link>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import { EventBus } from "./event-bus.js"; 
export default {
    name: 'OrderPlace',
    
    data(){
        return{
            successTitle:'Order placed Successfully',
            adminEmailSection:'Email-us',
            adminContactSection:'Contact-us',
            adminAddressSection:'Address',
            adminEmail:'admin@bookstore.com',
            adminMobNum:'+918163475881',
            orderNumber: ''
        }        
    },
    mounted() {  
      EventBus.$on("emitting-order", orderNo=> {  
      this.orderNumber = orderNo;
      console.log(`Oh, that's great ${orderNo})`); 
      return orderNo; 
      });  
   }  
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import "@/styles/OrderPlace.scss";
</style>
```

`event-bus.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue';  
export const EventBus = new Vue();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the orderPlace.vue component is not active when you do the emit. It cannot receive the element.
You can try to register your order number, in the localStorage. Or call orderPlace.vue as a child component and pass the order number to the props